# Create user accesstoken for android app

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, user-registration

I am making an android app where users have the option to register via email, facebook and gmail. I would like to provide the users with an accesstoken once their registration (irrespective of method) is confirmed. So every time the user does an api call, the access token would be sent. On the server side the user would be verified and permissions confirmed. After this, the requisite data would be sent.

1. Is this the correct way to do user authentication?
2. If yes then, how to do it? Are there SDKs that are good for this?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook it self provides an accesstoken when user logged in through Facebook. That accesstoken is used by server to access more details of current logged in user in app. refer this link to know more about login with Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Yes. I can get user information through facebook. But can I store the access token of the fb registered user on my database and use it to uniqueli identify the user and set permissions?

Answer (score -1):

you can store your session token in Shared preferences.

Set your token.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("token",<token-value>);  
editor.commit();
```

get your token

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String token = prefs.getString("token", <default-value>);
```

Comment: yes. I had planned to store the created access token this way. Just wanted to confirm if the method is correct.